# gstreamer gl with xorg7 gives bad display

Tags: opengl, gstreamer, buildroot, xorg, wayland

My project uses buildroot on a rockchip rk3288 processor (Tinkerboard). My project uses Qt and gstreamer. I am moving away from wayland/weston to x since the libmali gbm library provides me with eglfs_kms for my Qt app. I have used eglfs before, and its fast from bootup, simple, and doesnt depend on weston like wayland does.

This is my old configuration
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland ./MyGUIApplication
/usr/lib/libmali.so -> /usr/lib/libmali-wayland.so

This is my new configuration
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=eglfs_kms ./MyGUIApplication
/usr/lib/libmali.so -> /usr/lib/libmali-gbm.so

In order to get the gbm library, I have updated my buildroot config as such to remove wayland and added xorg7

```
@@ -69,6 +69,7 @@
 BR2_PACKAGE_GST1_PLUGINS_BASE_PLUGIN_VIDEOTESTSRC=y
 BR2_PACKAGE_GST1_PLUGINS_BASE_PLUGIN_VIDEORATE=y
 BR2_PACKAGE_GST1_PLUGINS_BASE_LIB_OPENGL=y
+# BR2_PACKAGE_GST1_PLUGINS_BASE_LIB_OPENGL_OPENGL is not set
 BR2_PACKAGE_GST1_PLUGINS_BASE_PLUGIN_ALSA=y
 BR2_PACKAGE_GST1_PLUGINS_BASE_PLUGIN_OGG=y
 BR2_PACKAGE_GST1_PLUGINS_BASE_PLUGIN_PANGO=y
@@ -124,13 +125,16 @@
 BR2_PACKAGE_E2FSPROGS_RESIZE2FS=y
 BR2_PACKAGE_GLMARK2=y
 BR2_PACKAGE_MESA3D_GALLIUM_DRIVER_SWRAST=y
+BR2_PACKAGE_MESA3D_OSMESA=y
 BR2_PACKAGE_PSPLASH=y
 BR2_PACKAGE_SDL2=y
 BR2_PACKAGE_SDL2_KMSDRM=y
+BR2_PACKAGE_SDL2_OPENGL=y
 BR2_PACKAGE_SDL2_OPENGLES=y
 BR2_PACKAGE_SDL2_TTF=y
 BR2_PACKAGE_QT5=y
 BR2_PACKAGE_QT5BASE_SQLITE_SYSTEM=y
+BR2_PACKAGE_QT5BASE_OPENGL_ES2=y
 BR2_PACKAGE_QT5BASE_LINUXFB=y
 BR2_PACKAGE_QT5BASE_EGLFS=y
 BR2_PACKAGE_QT5BASE_JPEG=y
@@ -142,9 +146,8 @@
 BR2_PACKAGE_QT5TOOLS=y
 BR2_PACKAGE_QT5TOOLS_LINGUIST_TOOLS=y
 BR2_PACKAGE_QT5VIRTUALKEYBOARD=y
-BR2_PACKAGE_QT5WAYLAND=y
-BR2_PACKAGE_WESTON=y
-BR2_PACKAGE_WESTON_DRM=y
+BR2_PACKAGE_XORG7=y
+BR2_PACKAGE_XKEYBOARD_CONFIG=y
 BR2_PACKAGE_AVRDUDE=y
 BR2_PACKAGE_EDID_DECODE=y
 BR2_PACKAGE_EVTEST=y
```

The problem is the gstreamer gl library doesnt work with this new configuration.

```
# gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! glupload ! glfiltercube ! gldownload ! fakesink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Got context from element 'gldownloadelement0': gst.gl.GLDisplay=context, gst.gl.GLDisplay=(GstGLDisplay)"\(GstGLDisplayEGL\)\ gldisplayegl0";
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstGLFilterCube:glfiltercube0: Failed to initialize egl: EGL_BAD_DISPLAY
Additional debug info:
gstglbasefilter.c(395): gst_gl_base_filter_decide_allocation (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstGLFilterCube:glfiltercube0
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

when running the GST_DEBUG="*:4" I get the following specific errors:

```
INFO GST_CONTEXT gstglutils.c:115:pad_query:<glfiltercube0:sink> pad peer query failed
INFO   glcontext gstglcontext.c:337:gst_gl_context_new: creating a context for display <gldisplayegl0>, user choice:(null)
INFO    glwindow gstglwindow.c:251:gst_gl_window_new: creating a window, user choice:(null)
INFO    glwindow gstglwindow_x11.c:141:gst_gl_window_x11_new: Wrong display type 32 for this window type 1
WARN    glwindow gstglwindow.c:293:gst_gl_window_new: Could not create window. user specified (null), creating dummy window
INFO   glcontext gstglcontext.c:1240:gst_gl_context_create_thread:<glcontextegl0> Attempting to create opengl context. user chosen api(s) (any), compiled api support (gles2) display api (opengl opengl3 gles2)
WARN        glcontext gstglcontext.c:1244:gst_gl_context_create_thread:<glcontextegl0> Failed to create context
INFO        glcontext gstglcontext.c:1046:gst_gl_context_create:<glcontextegl0> gl thread created
WARN     glbasefilter gstglbasefilter.c:395:gst_gl_base_filter_decide_allocation:<glfiltercube0> error: Failed to initialize egl: EGL_BAD_DISPLAY
INFO GST_ERROR_SYSTEM gstelement.c:2145:gst_element_message_full_with_details:<glfiltercube0> posting message: Failed to initialize egl: EGL_BAD_DISPLAY
INFO GST_ERROR_SYSTEM gstelement.c:2172:gst_element_message_full_with_details:<glfiltercube0> posted error message: Failed to initialize egl: EGL_BAD_DISPLAY ERROR: from element / GstPipeline:pipeline0/
```

The other gstreamer libraries work fine, but I need the gstopengl library for efficient transformations, so using software plugins like geometric transform are not acceptable.

I'm not a noob with the display concepts, but I am not an expert. Am I missing something from buildroot which gstgl needs in order to work correctly ?